# How to enable Tomcat debugging

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat installed on the server and I want to be able to check if debuggin is disabled/enabled. I searched everywhere and found the instructions below:

```
1. Open the user interface and navigate to Administration > System Management > Hosts > UI Server.
2. Select "Use local settings" and check the boxes for Enable Tomcat Logging and Enable Tomcat Debugging.
3. Save the changes and restart the services when prompted.
```

The problem is it is not clear whether I need to install an additional admin console to access those features. I would appreciate any help or pointers in the right direction. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

To enable debugging in tomcat you can use **JPDA**. JPDA stands for **Java Platform Debugger Architecture** and it's the tool for creating debugging applications.

To enable debugging, you need to specify two things.

1. One is the Transport mechanism that moves bits between the debugger and debugee.
2. The other is the address where the debugging connections get accepted.

Now depending upon the location of the debugger and debugee the transport mechanism could be different.

Export the transport and address variables as shown below.

```bash
export JPDA_ADDRESS=8000
export JPDA_TRANSPORT=dt_socket
```

After setting the variables, you can start your tomcat using the following command.

```bash
sudo catalina.sh jpda start
```

I am assuming you have set up your `TOMCAT_HOME` environment variables properly if not then start it by going to the bin directory of tomcat and use `catalina.sh jpda start` command.

The other way to launch tomcat in debugging mode is by using `JAVA_OPTS`. After setting the environment variables you can execute the following command.

```bash
export JAVA_OPTS="-Xdebug –Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=8080"
```

In the above command the transport mechanism is `dt_socket`. It means the transport mechanism used for sending the bits between the debugger and debuggee is socket transport mechanism. The other transport mechanism is `dt_shmem` (`shmem` for shared memory). If you want to remotely debug then go for socket mechanism. If you do not want to debug a distant computer (the debugger and the debugee is in the same system) then you will use shared memory.

The value `suspend=y` tells the JVM to start in suspended mode and stay suspended until a debugger is attached to it.

The value `server=y` is used to open a socket and listen for incoming debugger requests.

After that run the command, `sudo sh catalina.sh  run`

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your response. I am actually just looking for way to check if debugging is enabled or disabled. And possibly to enable it in prod. Is it disabled by default? How do I check?

Comment: Do you suggest setting that in JAVA_OPTS or in CATALINA_OPTS?

Answer (score 2):

I believe debugging is installed, but not active by default. The way to tell is to look at your start script, bin/catalina.sh or bin/startup.sh. When you execute startup.sh, by default tomcat will start in regular execution mode. You can also start with 
`./catalina.sh start`
which calls startup.sh after setting some variables which get passed to the startup.sh script. When you execute catalina.sh with the jpda argument, 
`./catalina.sh jpda start`
it will build the arguments to start tomcat in debug mode. If you can access your application after starting tomcat with 
`./catalina.sh jpda start` 
your application is running in debug mode.

Runtime info is logged to logs/catalina.out, so if there was a problem that prevented catalina.sh from starting tomcat, you will likely find it there.

Below are the default settings for the catalina.sh jpda option. If you want to change these, you can modify it in catalina.sh, startup.sh, setenv.sh (I had to make one of these after installing tomcat 8) or write a custom startup script that sets the debug transport and address, then calls catalina or startup with the appropriate options to launch in debug mode (the "agentlib" line below).

```
if [ "$1" = "jpda" ] ; then
    if [ -z "$JPDA_TRANSPORT" ]; then
        JPDA_TRANSPORT="dt_socket"
    fi
    if [ -z "$JPDA_ADDRESS" ]; then
        JPDA_ADDRESS="localhost:8000"
    fi
    if [ -z "$JPDA_SUSPEND" ]; then
        JPDA_SUSPEND="n"
    fi
    if [ -z "$JPDA_OPTS" ]; then
```

JPDA_OPTS="agentlib:jdwp=transport=$JPDA_TRANSPORT,address=$JPDA_ADDRESS,server=y,suspend=$JPDA_SUSPEND"
        fi
            CATALINA_OPTS="$JPDA_OPTS $CATALINA_OPTS"
        shift
    fi